# Android Notifications - Local and FCM Notification With Same Tag Won't Merge

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

Will Android merge a locally created notification with one from FCM if they have the same tag?

I am using Azure NotificationHub to send the FCM push notification, which I thought might be part of the problem.

However, using `adb dumpsys notification` I was able to see both the local and remote notification have the same tag but different ids

```
NotificationRecord(0x052975b7: pkg=com.app.to.test user=UserHandle{0} id=-1696176081 tag=1693951830-btevent ...

NotificationRecord(0x06121578: pkg=com.app.to.test user=UserHandle{0} id=-305082311 tag=1693951830-btevent ...
```

Anyone have any ideas why this wouldn't work?